# e-commerce customer credit deposit and payment

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, e-commerce

I have a small handy crafted clothing store which currently provides payment via cash only (credit card and bank transfer in my country is not popular and it costly). The store is self developed based on [this data model](http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/e_commerce/index.htm). And then one day a customer ask me if she can deposit some cash in to here account so she can make payment for her order. And withdraw it out if she want.

Because of that, I have googled a lot about the credit deposit system but most of them leading to the banking system which really big and of course it not suit my needs.

Is anyone experienced with this before? Could you please share the idea of your work or a diagram of database schema?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You are asking some thing like eWallet, If you want to provide eWallet to your customer, it's very complicated system, and each county have own policies regarding digital payment.

Still if you want to take advance money from customer for future, then you add one more SKU which is not any physical item, it will be totally logical just like gift card which have fix price like 1K, 2K, ..., if customer buy this item then you deduct money from that card...

@Duong Truong first time I try to reply on such question, so may be you unable to get propyl, but I have good idea to solve your problem, so you can directly call me  +919450303234